# Reduce Product Stock on Adding to Cart - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, stock

Got a (hopefully quick!) question on updating stock levels for products when they are added to the cart (and preferably "releasing" them back to stock if they are removed from the cart prior to checkout) - how easy is it to achieve something like this, and what would the best steps be?

I can see there are a few functions/filters that could be called in to play like woocommerce_stock_amount, wc_update_product_stock and add_to_cart_class and so forth, but I'd love any guidance you could spare on how to bring it all together :)

So far, this is what has been arrived at, and it's working well, but with one rather important issue! If a product is a "one-off", in other words, only has one available in stock before it is added to the cart, the visitor cannot checkout as the script below has reduced the stock to zero!

Thanks in advance for any help with this :)

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'update_product_stock_on_add', 10, 6);

function update_product_stock_on_add($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $product = get_product($product_id);

    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['old_stock_quantity'] = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['add_time'] = time();

    wc_update_product_stock($product_id, $product->get_stock_quantity() - $quantity);
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_cart_item_quantity_update', 'update_product_stock_on_update', 10, 2);

function update_product_stock_on_update($cart_item_key, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];

    wc_update_product_stock($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['old_stock_quantity'] - $quantity);
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_cart_item_quantity_zero', 'update_product_stock_on_zero', 10, 2);

function update_product_stock_on_zero($cart_item_key, $quantity) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_item = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];

    wc_update_product_stock($cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['old_stock_quantity']);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'load_old_stock_from_session', 10, 3);

function load_old_stock_from_session($cart_item, $values, $key) {
    $cart_item['old_stock_quantity'] = $values['old_stock_quantity'];
    $cart_item['add_time'] = $values['add_time'];

    return $cart_item;
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'check_cart_item_timeout');


function check_cart_item_timeout($cart) {
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        if ((time() - $values['add_time']) >= 10) {

            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s has been removed from your cart because it can no longer be purchased. Please contact us if you need assistance.', 'woocommerce' ), $values['data']->get_title() ), 'error' );
            unset($cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]);
            wc_update_product_stock($values['product_id'], $values['old_stock_quantity']);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Normally, it's *you* who should spare the answerers and for that you should present your problem in terms of [code you already tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ;)

Comment: @brasofilo Of course! Your wish is very much my command! I've nearly got it to where it needs to be, but there's a small problem with "one-off" items (e.g. those that only have a stock level of 1). Any thoughts?

Comment: You're changing stock values on in the session and not in the actual table, which is ok, but the question I would have is, why? Why bother adjusting stock levels for the viewer of the cart? What happens when you have a collision such that customer A adds item A to his cart, reducing his "session" stock to 0 (buys all of an item)  but while he is shopping, customer B logs in and buys 20% of the available stock of the item? Customer A's values are going to be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried this plugin? http://wisdmlabs.com/empty-cart-timer-woocommerce-plugin/  It should solve your problem to quite some extent.